# How to return bool from stored proc

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to work out how to write a store procdure which returns a boolean value. I started off writing the following one which returns an int.

```
USE [Database]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[ReturnInt]    Script Date: 09/30/2010 09:31:11 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[ReturnInt]  AS
RETURN 3
```

I'm unsure however how to write one to return a boolean value.

Can somebody help? Is it a bit value?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can't. There is no boolean datatype and the procedure return code can only be an `int`. You can return a `bit` as an output parameter though.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ReturnBit] 
@bit BIT OUTPUT
AS
    BEGIN
    SET @bit = 1
    END
```

And to call it

```
DECLARE @B BIT
EXEC [dbo].[ReturnBit] @B OUTPUT
SELECT @B
```

Comment: Depending on what you're doing you could use a function instead.

Answer (score 29):

Use this:

`SELECT CAST(1 AS BIT)`

Comment: Works for SQL 2012, don't know about previous

Comment: @sq33G - It works in all versions but it still does not return a **boolean**. It returns a single column single row result set containing a **bit**. They are not the same thing. You can't do `IF CAST(1 AS BIT) THEN ...`. My preference is to use output parameters rather than single column single row result sets anyway. `.NET` designers will map either to a CLR boolean.

Comment: Got it. Most of the time, I'm not using stored procedures within SQL, but rather to return data to .NET - so having a *bit* rather than a logical *boolean* doesn't make much difference to me.

Answer (score 8):

You have at least 2 options:

```
SELECT CONVERT(bit, 1)
SELECT CAST(1 AS bit)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @bitVariable bit     
SELECT @bitVariable = columnName FROM table WHERE id=id
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.