# Returning boolean value from a stored procedure using bit

Tags: asp.net, sql, stored-procedures

This is my code for a stored procedure that checks for Email availability.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_CheckEmailMobile](@Name VARCHAR(50), @Email NVARCHAR(50), @Password NVARCHAR(50), @CountryCode INT, @Mobile VARCHAR(50), @Result BIT OUTPUT)
AS 
BEGIN 


IF EXISTS (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM AUser WHERE  [Email] = @Email AND [Mobile] = @Mobile) 


SELECT 'FALSE'; --Email &/or Mobile does not exist in database

ELSE
 --Insert the record & register the user 
INSERT INTO [AUser] ([Name], [Email], [Password], [CountryCode], [Mobile]) VALUES (@Name, @Email, @Password, @CountryCode, @Mobile)  


END
```

How do I assign the result of this SP to @Result (its the output parameter)??

here is the cs CODE: Where am I going wron in this??

```
      protected void btnRegister_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]);
        con.Open();



        SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_CheckEmailMobile", con);
        Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        Cmd.CommandText = "Registration";
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmailAddress.Text);
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CountryCode", ddlCountryCode.Text);
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile", txtMobileNumber.Text);
        //Cmd.Parameters.Add("@Result", DbType.Boolean);
        SqlParameter sqlParam = new SqlParameter("@Result", DbType.Boolean);
        //sqlParam.ParameterName = "@Result";
        //sqlParam.DbType = DbType.Boolean;
        sqlParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        Cmd.Parameters.Add(sqlParam);
        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        Response.Write(Cmd.Parameters["@Result"].Value);

    }
```

went through this, dint help...
[How to run the stored procedure that has OUTPUT parameter from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433694/how-to-run-the-stored-procedure-that-has-output-parameter-from-c)

Comment: This would be useful: [How to return bool from stored proc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3825620/how-to-return-bool-from-stored-proc)

Comment: WENT THROUGH THAT ALREADY, DINT HELP...

Comment: Try using this method to get the value 
        Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); con.Close();
        cmd.Parameters["@Result"].Value;

Comment: tried.. no luck... 
BTW, I have revised the code. If you could have a look....

Comment: Check my updated answer the line where CommandText is setting causing problem and i have removed that line and its working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just set it as a normal variable like this

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_CheckEmailMobile](@Name VARCHAR(50), @Email NVARCHAR(50), @Password NVARCHAR(50), @CountryCode INT, @Mobile VARCHAR(50), @Result BIT OUTPUT)
    AS 
    BEGIN 


    IF EXISTS (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM AUser WHERE  [Email] = @Email AND [Mobile] = @Mobile) 
    BEGIN

    SELECT 'FALSE'; --Email &/or Mobile does not exist in database
    @Result = 0
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
     --Insert the record & register the user 
    INSERT INTO [AUser] ([Name], [Email], [Password], [CountryCode], [Mobile]) VALUES (@Name, @Email, @Password, @CountryCode, @Mobile)  

    @Result = 1
    END

    END
```

For server side code

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"]);
            con.Open();

            SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_CheckEmailMobile", con);
            Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txtEmailAddress.Text);
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text);
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CountryCode", ddlCountryCode.Text);
            Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile", txtMobileNumber.Text);
            SqlParameter sqlParam = new SqlParameter("@Result", DbType.Boolean);            
            sqlParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            Cmd.Parameters.Add(sqlParam);
            Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            Response.Write(Cmd.Parameters["@Result"].Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_CheckEmailMobile](@Name VARCHAR(50), @Email NVARCHAR(50), @Password NVARCHAR(50), @CountryCode INT, @Mobile VARCHAR(50), @Result BIT OUTPUT)
AS 
BEGIN 

Declare @result bit

IF EXISTS (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM AUser WHERE  [Email] = @Email AND [Mobile] = @Mobile) 
Begin

Set @result=0; --Email &/or Mobile does not exist in database
End
ELSE
Begin
 --Insert the record & register the user 
INSERT INTO [AUser] ([Name], [Email], [Password], [CountryCode], [Mobile]) VALUES (@Name, @Email, @Password, @CountryCode, @Mobile)  

Set @result=1 --True
End

Select @result as Result
END
```

**cs Code:**

```
bool? IsSuccess= YourDBObject.usp_CheckEmailMobile(all params).FirstOrDefault().Result;
```