# How to Pass Bool (BIT) parameter to SQL server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a stored procedure in sql which has a bit parameter.I need to pass the parameter value from c#.Can Someone help me how to do it. I passed true/false value to the bit parameter but it is not working.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE checkbit
      @id varchar(10),
@IsDeleted bit
AS
BEGIN

IF(@IsDeleted = 1)
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM tablename WHERE ID = @id

        RETURN
    END
END
```

My C# code

Im using entity framework.Checking for bit value here.

```
bool chk;
if(val==1)
 chk=true;
else
 chk=false;
context.checkbit(id,chk)
```

Comment: It's usual to post your code...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569860/passing-parameter-to-stored-procedure-in-c-sharp

Comment: For future questions it's very important to include details in the original question. The fact that you are using Entities is needed in order for this to be answered

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can just use `0` or `1` for the `BIT` field

- `1` for `TRUE`
- `0` for `FALSE`

---

```
context.checkbit(id,val);// ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: I am using entity framework here.I used true/false but it is not working.

Comment: Did you read my answer? I said use **numbers** either **0** or **1**

Comment: Why did SQL Server do this? I've been beating my head against a wall trying to find out why my bit value was not updating. I was setting the value to `true` and it executed with no errors, but the database kept showing `0`.

Comment: yes for SQL server there is no such things like true or false, only bit values

Comment: there is now? something like 'TRUE' and 'False' for SQL Server.  It converts those char to 0 or 1 for you. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/bit-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 4):

IF your using Ado.net then try with below hope it will work.

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
             param.ParameterName = "@Isstatus";
             param.Value = Isstatus;
             param.DbType = System.Data.DbType.Boolean
             cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

**Entity Framework**

if your sp return true or false then below you can use other wise you need to try with void.

```
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Data.Objects;

    public virtual bool Deletecustomer(int id ,bool IsDeleted )
    {
        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<bool>("EXEC checkbit({0},{1})", id,IsDeleted ).SingleOrDefault();
    }
```