# C# - Passing parameter to stored procedure and return IEnumerable

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, dapper

can I directly pass the parameter in the query as shown below?

There is error so anyone could help?

```
public IEnumerable ListTop10countries(string direction)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MYCON"].ToString()))
    {
        var list = con.Query<OutputCountries>("Usp_GetTop10", direction).AsEnumerable();       
        return list;
    }
}
```

Error:

```
An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Procedure or function 'Usp_GetTop10' expects parameter '@direction', which was not supplied.
```

The stored proc script as is below:

```
CREATE proc [dbo].[Usp_GetTop10]
@direction nvarchar(30)
as
begin
SELECT TOP 10 
      [country]    
      ,[Tons]
  FROM [master].[dbo].[a]
  where direction = @direction
  order by [Tons] Desc
end
GO
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569860/passing-parameter-to-stored-procedure-in-c-sharp

Comment: Can you please post the error you are getting ??

Comment: I have added the error and explained in more specific

Comment: Are you using Dapper.net?

Comment: yes, i am using Dapper as reference

Comment: May be this http://stackoverflow.com/a/5971847/1660178 will help you. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to call a stored procedure with Dapper?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5962117/is-there-a-way-to-call-a-stored-procedure-with-dapper)

Comment: yes offcourse but this is question about anything is wrong in his/her syntax..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
public IEnumerable ListTop10countries(string mydirection)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MYCON"].ToString()))
    {
         var list = con.Query<OutputCountries>("Usp_GetTop10", new {direction = mydirection}, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure).AsEnumerable();
         return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: hi @sangramparmar can you expound on this answer and connect the dots a bit more for me.  I"m sorry for asking this but this is a bit advance for me, i'm trying to figure out if Query is an extension method and for the type OutputCountries how do i create that type.  thanks in advance.

Comment: hi @Nel are you able to add on this.  I was trying to implement this but its a bit advance for me.  I think your implementing an extension method, with a type of Output countries. Do you have some more code you can add.  Thanks