# Sending parameter from combobox to stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, combobox

I am using SQL Server 2014 and Visual Studio 2013. I want to write C# code so that user should check checkbox and select an item from combobox then this item will be sent to a stored procedure in SQL Server. In real I want to send parameter to stored procedure from combobox. Code below written by me but does not work well.

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox1.Checked) ;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=USER-PC\----);
    SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("select_Info_Person", con);
    Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    con.Open();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    using(SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(Cmd))
    {
        da.Fill(dt);

        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Person_Expert";
        comboBox1.DataSource = dt;

        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Where is the parameter you are trying to pass to the stored procedure?

Comment: Till now you didn't passed any parameter to SP. You can pass parameter e.g. `Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yourparameter", cbo.SelectedValue);`

Comment: i think you have missed the strong typed parameter in your sqlCommand. Check this on "how to pass your value to the stored procedure".http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15569860/passing-parameter-to-stored-procedure-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that  you are not sending any parameter to the Stored procedure

Step 1:

Declare Parameter in your storedprocedure and use it in where condition..

```
CREATE PROCEDURE select_Info_Person 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @p1 int = 0
AS
BEGIN
    -

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    Select * from  PersonMaster where personID=@p1
END
GO
```

Then in the code

```
private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CheckBox.Checked) ;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=USER-PC\----");
    SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("select_Info_Person", con);
    Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString());
  //  or if you dont have value feild
  //  Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", comboBox1.Selecteditem.Text.ToString());
    con.Open();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(Cmd))
    {
        da.Fill(dt);
//I cannot understand what you are doing using below            

// comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Person_Expert";
           // comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
           // con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

No problem, if SP is without any parameter. It seems your connection string is not properly initialized, otherwise no problem at all. Check the Error type and share. Otherwise OK.